# Python 3 TypeError: 'int' object is not callable, but what is the fault here?

Tags: python-3.x

currently I am leraning Python 3 and I am facing here the following problem within my blackjack card game code.

The output is the result of the player.points() function, I was testing it outside of the written code and it worked well like that, so I dont get it where the Error Message comes from, any hints or ideas?

````
```
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time
import random
import emoji

class Player():
    
    def __init__(self, account,name):
        self.name = name
        self.account = account
        self.betbox = 0
        self.cards = [[]]
        self.points = 0
        self.status = True # True -> Player, False -> Spectator
        
    def bet(self,bet):
        self.betbox = int(bet)
        self.account -= int(bet)
    
    def get_card(self, card, deck_of_cards=0):
        self.cards[deck_of_cards].append(card)
    
    def points(self):
        for i,cards in enumerate(self.cards):
            for card in self.cards[i]:
                print(card)
    

    def __str__(self):
        player_string = ""
        name_string = "Player: "+ str(self.name)
        cards_string = ""
        account_string = "Account: "+ str(self.account)
        betbox_string = "Betbox: "+ str(self.betbox)
        points_string = "points to be calculated"
        for i,deck_of_cards in enumerate(self.cards):
            for j,card in enumerate(deck_of_cards):
                cards_string += str(self.cards[i][j]) +" "
        return "\n\n"+ name_string +"\n"+ cards_string +"\n"+ account_string +"\n"+ betbox_string +"\n"+ points_string
    

class Dealer(Player):
    
    def __init__(self,account,name):
        Player.__init__(self, account,name)
        self.stack = []

    def __str__(self):
            player_string = ""
            name_string = "Dealer: "+ str(self.name)
            cards_string = ""
            account_string = "Account: "+ str(self.account)
            betbox_string = "Betbox: "+ str(self.betbox)
            points_string = "points to be calculated"
            for i,deck_of_cards in enumerate(self.cards):
                for j,card in enumerate(deck_of_cards):
                    cards_string += str(self.cards[i][j]) +" "
            return "\n\n"+ name_string +"\n"+ cards_string +"\n"+ account_string +"\n"+ betbox_string +"\n"+ points_string
                 
    def new_stack_of_cards(self):
        value=["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King","Ace"]
        color=[emoji.emojize(':heart_suit:'), emoji.emojize(':spade_suit:'), emoji.emojize(':club_suit:'), emoji.emojize(':diamond_suit:')]
        i = 0
        while i < 4:
            for v in value:
                for c in color:
                    self.stack.append(Card())
                    self.stack[-1].new(v,c)
            i += 1
            random.shuffle(self.stack)

    def card(self):
        return self.stack.pop()

class Table():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.table = []
    
    def initialize(self):
        input_string = ""
        name_strings = []
        while True:
            input_string = input()
            if input_string == "q":
                break
            name_strings.append(input_string)
        return name_strings
    
    def view(self):
        table = ""
        for player in self.table:
            table += str(player) 
        time.sleep(5)
        clear_output()
        print(table)

class Card():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "2"
        self.color = emoji.emojize(':heart_suit:')

    
    def new(self, value, color):
        self.value = value
        self.color = color
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.color) + str(self.value)
````

```
blackjack = Table()

dealer = Dealer(1000000,"d")
dealer.new_stack_of_cards()

name_strings = blackjack.initialize()

for i,player in enumerate(name_strings):
    blackjack.table.append(Player(10000,name_strings[i]))
blackjack.table.append(dealer)

for player in blackjack.table[:-1]:
    player.bet(input())
    
for player in blackjack.table:
    player.get_card(dealer.card())    
blackjack.view()

for player in blackjack.table[:-1]:
    player.get_card(dealer.card())
blackjack.view()


for player in blackjack.table:
    player.points()
```

```
    output:
```

```
Player: 1
♥10 ♥2 
Account: 9999
Betbox: 1
points to be calculated

Player: 2
♣10 ♣Jack 
Account: 9998
Betbox: 2
points to be calculated

Dealer: d
♥Ace 
Account: 1000000
Betbox: 0
points to be calculated

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-1a19c3780b6f> in <module>
     25 
     26 for player in blackjack.table:
---> 27     player.points()
     28 
     29 

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Player` class, `points` is an integer, and cannot be called. I see that the method `points` has been commented out.

```py
    for player in blackjack.table:
        player.points()
```

From this code, it looks like you want to call the method `points`, but you are instead trying to call an integer stored in the `points` attribute.

Uncomment the method, and change the name of either the method or the attribute.

Comment: Ah got it, points seems to be a python fuction or sth like that, I renamed it simply and solved it on thy way

Comment: Basically your content does not fit to my solution but it was stimulating me in a good way. The solution is very simple: There is an points() method available through the import's that I've done, a system-method like print() or len(), that's why I couldn't call my own fuction. Solved by new name for my method, its named now: calculate_points() instead of points().

Comment: @thewayoflove That is not the case. the `points` method in your player object is separate from the imported `points` function. calling `player.points()` does not call the imported function. The problem was that you had defined `self.points = 0` inside the player object, and later called `player.points()`, which would be the same as writing `0()`. That is where the error message `'int' object is not callable` comes from. Marking this answer as a solution would be correct.